# WriteableBitmap without antialiasing

Tags: c#, wpf, writablebitmap

Im using the http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/
WPF dll. 
For drawing objects on a writeablebitmap.
Now I dont want to have antialised pixels.

for example I draw a circle

```
using (writeableBmp.GetBitmapContext())
                {
                    writeableBmp.FillEllipse((int)origin.X, (int)origin.Y, (int)(origin.X + ell.Width), (int)(origin.Y + ell.Height), Colors.Blue);

                }
               img.Source = writeableBmp.Resize(68, 42, WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.NearestNeighbor);
```

I want to have sharp edges.

Why do I need that?
 I have LED strips with a resolution of 68 x 42 and I write a WPF application to control
 them.
any idea i can manage that?

UPDATE: 
the solution of my problem is quite simple
just set the RenderOptions

> RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(i,
>   BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor);
>               RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(i, EdgeMode.Aliased